# Why doesn't Mathematica find solution for differential equation when Wolfram Alpha does?

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving

I need to solve differential equation:
dy/dx=tan(1/2*(Pi/2+arctan((|3tan(35*Pi/180)-x|)/(y+3)))), y(0)=0 
Wolfram Alpha gives me the output in shape of plot and I need to get the formula used by engine to draw it.

[image: Plots from Wolfram Alpha]

But when I tried to put the same equation into the Mathematica, it doesn't work and gives me this error message:

[image]

I used "Reduce" function but it just gives me even more errors.
I am beginner in using Mathematica, could you please tell me what do I do wrong?

Comment: It looks like Wolfram Alpha solved it numerically.  Use `NDSolve` in Mathematica to get the same numerical solution as WA.